# how can shows wsdl from internet by new address (own address)?

Tags: web-services, wsdl, cxf, mule

i want use wsdl form internet in mule such as :http://www.ommolketab.org/OML_News.asmx?WSDL
i want to :
after that i write `[http://localhost:8082/myservice?wsdl][2]`
be showed wsdl from address http://www.ommolketab.org/OML_News.asmx?WSDL 
  i left my flow here it is very simple

```
   <cxf:configuration name="CXF_Configuration1" configurationLocation="http://www.ommolketab.org/OML_News.asmx" enableMuleSoapHeaders="true" initializeStaticBusInstance="true" doc:name="CXF Configuration"/>
<flow name="service-cxf-wsdlfirstFlow1" doc:name="service-cxf-wsdlfirstFlow1">
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" address="http://localhost:8882/OrderSvcs" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <cxf:proxy-service configuration-ref="CXF_Configuration1"    payload="envelope" doc:name="SOAP" enableMuleSoapHeaders="false" namespace="http://tempuri.org/" service="OML_News"/>
</flow>
```

[image]

Comment: could you please re-phrase your question? Thanks

Comment: Please be more specific

Comment: @Satya i eddited, is it suitable?

Comment: @Sercan ozdemir  i eddited, is it suitable?

Comment: @Maryam, looks fine , so what I understand, is whenever someone clicks on your local URL it should fetch content from ommolketab URL and show . right ?

Comment: @Satya yes satya can u help me?

Comment: in your question you are accessing the localhost on 8082 whereas in your config you are trying to access it on 8882 , is this a typographical error or you may want to look at it ?

Comment: @Satya excuse me  typographical

Comment: @Satya can you help me more i hope u

Comment: @Satya, i eddited, is it suitable?

Answer (score 1):

The value you have in `namespace` looks like the value that's typically in `wsdlLocation`.

Also `port="80"` is clearly wrong: a SOAP Port is not an HTTP port. Check the WSDL for the real value.

Finally, can you show what's configured by the `CXF_Configuration1` element?

Comment: I change some value and clear port=80 I left all my configure can u check it and help me more i don't what did i configure really?

Comment: @Satya can you help me more i hope u

Comment: @genjosanzo can you help me more i hope u

Comment: @brelian can you help me more i hope u

Comment: i put value for wsdlLocationand my program is correct now thanks a lot from all